# nhibernate guid performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, nhibernate, guid

What would be the overhead of using GUID's instead of an integer identity in nHibernate for table primary keys?

The main reason for use would be the obfuscation of table ids on user facing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impact on the day to day level for operations like *GetById*, *Find* first 50 filtered records, *Delete*, *Update*... zero. There is no measurable difference at all.

What will be effected a lot is the Database - **storage**. Integer is stored in 4 bytes, Guid consumes 16. So on every million rows you will need 12 MB more of storage. In case that such an entity references other(s) it is another 12 MB per every referenced table. 
And when such columns are used for indexes... spaces could grow more and more.

So on a larger scale, SQL server will have to scan larger piece of data. 
For example MS SQL Server is really optimized for int types. (including bigint, shortint, tinyint).

*BUT, to be honest, we were using both approaches, and performance issue was always elsewhere...*

I would vote for primary keys based on  **int** every time - if possible.

Rather later change the MVC routing from controller\action\id to something else, but keep ids int. You can introduce GUID as a property (consuming some space but only ones, not in referenced tables) and change routing to *controller\actin\uniqueGuid* and on your business layer you will call GetByGuid if really needed to obfuscate users.